# Save and load JavaFX TableView using Properties

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, properties-file

Is there a decent way of doing this? I populate the TableView with an enum and use its getters to add values to the columns, like so:

`taskColumn.setCellValueFactory(a -> new SimpleStringProperty(a.getValue().getAssignmentName()));`

`tableView.getItems().addAll(Tasks.values());`

I have a lot of editable rows which the user could change to customize the way the program will work, but doing so everytime the program launches would be very tedious.

What I want to do is get ALL the values from the columns and save them using `java.util.Properties`, which I can then load into the TableView so the user does not need to re-configure the next time the program is launched.

I have to use Properties for this particular assignment but I'm open to any suggestions on how I can make this simpler.

Comment: Yes, of course you can do this (though a properties file is probably not the simplest way). You can get the values by calling `getItems()` on the table and iterating through the list, getting the appropriate properties from each item (each item represents a row).

Comment: Is there any chance you could show a small snippet of how I'd go about doing it? Been at it for like 2 days and I'm not sure how to go about it. Btw, been seeing your posts all over the place whilst searching for help and you are a massive help already! Thank you :)

Comment: Not from the information you've provided, no - it is too vague. You should create a [MCVE] (a new, complete project that does just enough to show the way you have your table and its data defined). It's really difficult to provide a detailed answer when all you provide is a description, instead of an actual example. Show what you have tried and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: I think I have an idea of how to do this now actually, with the information you provided me. I appreciate it, James.

I will come back and post a full example if nothing works. Will also post a solution to my problem for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution is to work with CSV format for saving user data.
This is an example of [CSV work](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2016/06/read-csv-file-display-in-javafx.html).

Other idea is JSON serialization/deserialization.

As already mentioned by @James_D some your project details are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've managed to get it to work though and posted the solution I went with below :)

Answer (score 0):

I said I would post the solution if I managed to get it working, and here's what I personally went with. I use Json with Properties to save and load. Completely open to suggestions and criticism! I now populate the tableview the traditional way instead of directly with the enum. That was bad design for what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks @James_D for the suggestions.

```
private EventHandler<ActionEvent> saveSettings() {
    return event -> {
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        JsonArray tasks = new JsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
            JsonObject task = new JsonObject();
            ObservableList<Info> info = tableView.getItems();
            task.addProperty("Name", info.get(i).getName());
            task.addProperty("Assignment", info.get(i).getAssignment());
            task.addProperty("Skip", info.get(i).isSkip());
            task.addProperty("Bar", info.get(i).getBar());
            tasks.add(task);
        }
        array.add(tasks);
        properties.setProperty("Settings", array.toString());
    };
}

private EventHandler<ActionEvent> loadSettings() {
    return event -> {
        String settings = properties.getProperty("Settings");
        if (settings != null) {
            tableView.getItems().clear();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray array = parser.parse(settings).getAsJsonArray();
            JsonArray tasks = array.get(0).getAsJsonArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject task = tasks.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                tableView.getItems().add(new Info(task.get("Name").getAsString(), getAssignment(task.get("Assignment").getAsString()),
                        task.get("Skip").getAsBoolean(), task.get("Bar").getAsInt()));
            }
        }
    };
}
```